# can not install any program through wine

Tags: wine, software-installation

i am currently using ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit version in my pc and i have installed wine software to run some .exe format files of windows in linux but it doesnt happen whenever i right click on the available file and select the option to install open it through wine it says access denied as shown in this image
[image]

and when i tried to install subway surfers through this terminal command i get this error
[image]

is there any solution for this question 
*edit
[image]
[image]

Comment: you souldn't run wine with sudo. Does your .exe file have execution priviliges (right click, properties, permissions)?

Comment: i cannot get the way to install it as i click on run with wine it opens it location   i have shown this in my edited question

Comment: hoe to get it done

Comment: If you want a simpler way of using wine, I suggest you install "Play on Linux" which gives a graphical way of installing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't that be `sudo chown -R agha:agha ~/.wine -R`? Also, never run a wine program with sudo. If that doesn't work, delete the existing prefix and create a new one with `sudo rm ~/.wine -R; winecfg`.

Comment: but how should i install that program as both the terminal command show the same error saying wine is not owned by you

Comment: is there any other way to handle that

Comment: I don't know what you might be doing wrong with wine, but you might as well delete the existing wine prefix and create a new one. `sudo rm ~/.wine -R; winecfg` You just install a program like one would normally do -> open the exe of the installer with wine without running sudo.

Comment: when i open it through wine installer it location is opened not but it doesnt gets installed